# cfthread - how long can it run?

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, railo, cfthread

Using Railo, I am processing large video files using cfthread. After the file is uploaded, I call `<cfthread type="task">` to process the file using ffmpeg (type="task" is Railo specific). For large files, this can take a while, and it looks like my threads are being terminated before they complete.

1) How can I verify that the threads are being terminated?

2) Is there a way to change how long a thread can run?

3) What's the best way to monitor thread activity in Railo?

Comment: Check the thread.log and requesttimeout.log in {web-root-directory}/WEB-INF/railo/logs/. I use the default task type (daemon) and set a request timeout within the thread to override the global request timeout. Doesn't seem to work with type="task" though (using Lucee rather than Railo).

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think the threads are not completing?

Comment: I'm determining that the threads aren't completing because the files never get processed even though I know the processing has started (I'm doing some logging). I'll check the railo log files as Jeremy suggested.

Comment: When I have thread issues, the exception log has good information.

Comment: Is there anyway to catch when a thread is terminated due to a request timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Check the thread.log and requesttimeout.log in {web-root-directory}/WEB-INF/railo/logs/. Use the default task type (daemon) and set a request timeout within the thread to override the global request timeout. Doesn't seem to work with type="task" though (using Lucee rather than Railo)